# Atomically accessing a variable which isn't a `std::atomic`

Tags: c++, atomic

We have some old code which we're updating to use more modern c++. It previously relied on the (yucky) visual studio extension for `volatile` to access a variable atomically.

The function is something like

```
T ReadAq(T* val)
{
    return *(volatile T*)val;
}
```

Note that the `T` is suitably aligned and small enough for the architectures we support to be natively able to a single read without ripping.

There's similar functionality for writing to the variable and all uses of the variable go through one of those functions.

And I don't really want to change its signature (as that would be a massive change to all callers) so I want to be able to do something like:

```
T ReadAq(T* val)
{
    return std::atomic_read(val, std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

But it seems like functionality like this doesn't exist in the standard - all atomic operations are on std::atomic types. Any ideas on whether its possible to fix this without changing the signature of `ReadAq`?

Comment: Would using a mutex be too expensive?

Comment: @Arcinde Yeah these are all meant to be small atomic operations (if we were writing this now it'd just be a plain std::atomic). Using a mutex would render the atomic part useless.

Comment: You could do something really nasty like assume that the implementation of std::atomic has no member variables other than the actual data member and therefore `(std::atomic<T>*)val` might work? You should probably at least add a sanity check to ensure the pointer is correctly aligned and that the implementation of std::atomic<T> is lock free.

Comment: @AlanBirtles If we're going the way of UB, I would make it clear with `reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<T>*>(val)`. C-style casts should not be used in C++.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is indeed a gap in the language and there's a Proposal to fix it for c++ 20:

> [p0019R7: Atomic Ref](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0019r7.html)
>
> Abstract: Extension to the atomic operations library to allow atomic
>   operations to apply to non-atomic objects
>
> An atomic reference is used to perform atomic operations on a
>   referenced non-atomic object. The intent is for atomic reference to
>   provide the best-performing implementation of atomic operations for
>   the non-atomic object type. All atomic operations performed through an
>   atomic reference on a referenced non-atomic object are atomic with
>   respect to any other atomic reference that references the same object,
>   as defined by equality of pointers to that object. The intent is for
>   atomic operations to directly update the referenced object. An atomic
>   reference constructor may acquire a resource, such as a lock from a
>   collection of address-sharded locks, to perform atomic operations.
>   Such atomic reference objects are not lock free and not address free.
>   When such a resource is necessary, subsequent copy and move
>   constructors and assignment operators may reduce overhead by copying
>   or moving the previously acquired resource as opposed to re-acquiring
>   that resource.
>
> Introducing concurrency within legacy codes may require replacing
>   operations on existing non-atomic objects with atomic operations such
>   that the non-atomic object cannot be replaced with an atomic object.
>
> An object may be heavily used non-atomically in well-defined phases of
>   an application. Forcing such objects to be exclusively atomic would
>   incur an unnecessary performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a careful cast:

```
template<class T>
T ReadAq(T* val) {
    using AT = std::atomic<T>;
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(AT), "Incompatible layout.");
    static_assert(alignof(T) == alignof(AT), "Incompatible layout.");
    return reinterpret_cast<AT*>(val)->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

Comment: This breaks strict aliasing